# How to upload and save multiple images to Rails API from JS frontend

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby, multipartform-data, rails-api

I am sending data from ReactJS as multipart/form-data to Rails API like this:

```js
const submitProduct = formData => {
  const config = {
    method: "PATCH",
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    body: formData
  }
  return fetch(PRODUCT_URL, config)
    .then(res => res.json());
}
```

On the Rails side I use ActiveStorage and attach images in `update` action like this:

```rb
if params[:images].present?
    params[:images].each do |image|
        @product.images.attach(image)
    end
end
```

Is there a better (cleaner) way to attach multiple images on the Rails side?

My env:

```
Ruby 3.0.1
Rails 6.1.4.1
```

Ref:

- https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.1/active_storage_overview.html#has-many-attached

Answer (score 1):

If your `params[:images]` is an array of of uploaded file objects, you should be able to attach it all at once like so

```
@product.images.attach(params[:images])
```

See here for more info: https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Attached/Many.html#method-i-attach